# componentWillReceiveProps() triggering for all child components

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have 4 components those are added in App.jsx file.I'm trying to change the contents inside the component B when state changes occured in A and same way content of D has to change when changes occured in C. Here I used actions and reducers.The problem what I am facing is that whenever changes happening any of the component componentWillReceiveProps() method of all the class\componet is triggering

```
class App extends React.Component {
   render() {
       const { dispatch, visibleTodos } = this.props
      return (
         <div >


            <A ongetAppStatusCick = {text =>  dispatch(AppStatusfromServer(text))}  />

            <B todos = {visibleTodos} />


            <C  ongetAppStatusCicknew = {text =>
               dispatch(AppStatusApplicationDetail(text))} />

            <D />





         </div>
      );
   }
}

function select(state) {
   return {
      visibleTodos: state.todos
   }
}

export default connect(select)(App)`
```

Comment: Well yes, because all the components are being rerendered thus all the components *will receive props*.

Comment: Ohh is it? Thanks for the update. One more doubt in case if I am adding a child component <E /> to the class D and wish to make change the contents of E on a button click of D, at that time also all componets recieves props or I can restrict props to recieve only for E.

Comment: Any help on the above one?

Comment: you decide where the props update depending on where you modify the state. When a component rerenders, so do all its children.